# Отнять текущее время

Tags: дата, javascript

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как отнять текущее локальное время пользователя в этом коде:
    var tl = new Date();
    tl.setDate((tl.getDate() + 1);
Нужно чтобы счетчик в полночь обнулялся и показывал оставшееся время до полуночи.

Answer (score 1):

Ну как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/DG9jD/1/

```
function midNight(output) {
    var $out = $(output),
        counter = new Date(),
        hrs = counter.getHours(),
        min = counter.getMinutes(),
        sec = counter.getSeconds(),
        midnight = (23-hrs) + " часов, " + (59-min) + " минут, " + (59-sec) + " секунд.";

    $out.text(midnight);

    // recursion
    setTimeout(function(){ midNight(output); }, 1000);      
}

midNight('#midnight__count');
```

Answer (score -1):

вместо `59-sec` должно быть `60-sec` .
Вот вариант без `JQuery`

```js
function midNight(output) {
    var out = document.getElementById(output);
 counter = new Date();
 hrs = counter.getHours();
 min = counter.getMinutes();
 sec = counter.getSeconds();
 midnight = (23-hrs) + " часов, " + (59-min) + " минут, " + (60-sec) + " секунд.";

    out.innerHTML = midnight;

    // recursion
    setTimeout(function(){ midNight(output); }, 1000);      
}

midNight('midnight__count');
```

```html
<div>До полуночи осталось: <span id="midnight__count"></span></div>
```

Comment: Вы взяли чужой ответ, модифицировали его и сделали отдельным ответом. Это моветон.

Правильней будет оставить комментарий к первому ответу.

Comment: @compl Вы правы, но у меня нет 50 баллов, чтобы комментировать.

Comment: Верно. Про это я и забыл.